# Ambiguous method while testing

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm trying to test the method `calculate` from `MyClass`:

```
// TestClass {
@Test
public void testCalculate() {
    MyClass tester = new MyClass();
    assertEquals((long)123, tester.calculate().get(5));
}

// MyClass
public ArrayList<Long> calculate() {} // signature
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
The method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type TestClass
```

What am I doing wrong? The return type of `calculate` is an `ArrayList` with `long`-values and I expect the `long` number 123.

When I do the following, it works:

```
// TestClass {
@Test
public void testCalculate() {
    MyClass tester = new MyClass();
    ArrayList<Long> arr = new ArrayList<Long>();
    arr.add((long) 123);
    assertEquals(arr.get(0), tester.calculate().get(5));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call to `assertEquals` has one argument of type `long` and the other of type `Long`. Use one of the following:

```
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(123L), tester.calculate().get(5));
```

or

```
assertEquals(123L, tester.calculate().get(5).longValue());
```

(I suggest using a `long` literal `123L` rather than a cast to a `long` of an `int` literal.)